# Iframe pdf set url throwing warning

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, iframe, blob

I am using Chrome webbrowser.

I have scenario like this: Get application/pdf from the server, create blob, create url from that blob, create iFrame set url and append to body.

What I get is info/warning:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "blob:http%3A//localhost/44655364-1927-426b-b158-04db3f0f1c6f"

Same things happen if I will just put Iframe in index.html and set src to any pdf from internet.

How I can get rid of this warning/info?

Comment: Iframes are not made for embedding PDFs into your website, although it will work. Here are some of the recommended ways of embedding PDFs into your website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html.

Comment: I know, I dont want to embed PDF into my site but only iframe has option to print the pdf content as I want to click button on the site and then redirect to printing without previewing the pdf on the site.